# Discharge protection circuit for 2S Li-ion

Tags: lithium-ion, low-power

I'm looking for a overdischarge protection circuit for two 18650 in series. Preferably not a module. Discharge current is max 1mA. Charging is done in a separate charger

My situation is a circuit with a power consumption of avg 1mA@3.3V. I would like to use 18650 batteries for a long runtime and ability to recharge. To use these batteries a undervoltage protection is recommended. Now I'm looking for a way to tackle this. A circuit with self low power consumption that shuts down the battery-connection at a reasonable voltage level.

Can this maybe a solution?

> -The BQ296xxx family has a self-disable function to turnoff the regulated output if any cell voltage falls below a certain
>   threshold,thereby preventing drain on the battery,and provides an
>   external control to enable or disable the regulated output.

page 15
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq2962.pdf